# Is it possible to solve the following grid with the given rules

Tags: algorithm, computer-science

**Note: This is not a homework question.**

you can think of this is a programming question, and the answer is whether there is a solution for it.

I was talking to my friend a few day ago, and I ask him to solve a simple puzzle game. The game is some what like a Sudoku and after 10 minutes, he gave up and told me there is no solution for it.

**The game works like this:**

Given a blank 9x9 grid, your objective is to fill it with colours (red, blue, green) so that each column, row, and each of the nine 3×3 sub-grids contains only 3 red, 3 blue, and 3 green.

**Rules:**

1. Each row/column/3x3 sub-grid must contain only 3 red, 3 blue, 3 green.
2. No 3 same colours can appear next to each other in any row/column (eg. RRRBGBGBG is not allow, but RRGGBRGBB is allow)

To anyone still interested in the question..here is a addition rule.

3. 3x3 squares can't be repeated. Now it is going to be harder from @Pavel Pája Halbich

**Question:**

Is there a solution?

Comment: Is there a solution to sudoku such that 123 are never all 3 adjacent, 456 are never adjacent, and 789 are never all 3 adjacent? If so, then look at that sudoku and color 123 red, 456 blue and 789 green

Comment: This is like the ternary version of the [binary puzzle](http://www.binarysudokupuzzle.com/rules-binary-puzzle/)

Comment: @harold Thank you, I was wondering if such thing exists already :)

Comment: It's different enough that a solution may or may not exist though, I'm looking for one now

Comment: Please migrate to mathematics.SE

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand it correctly, this is a valid solution, right?

[image: Solution]

Comment: that turned out to be less interesting than I had hoped

Comment: @harold Well, this was easy. But imagine that we extend the rules with 3) 3x3 squares can't be repeated. Now it is going to be harder :)

Comment: well. i thought the question was interesting, apparently, not. :(

Comment: @theaxis If you want to make games like this, you should study mathematics. For example Sudoku can be "translated" to problems with Latin squares (https://www.cs.utexas.edu/~kuipers/readings/Sudoku-sciam-06.pdf)

Answer (score 2):

With the suggested extra rule "3x3 squares cannot be repeated", this works:

```
1 1 2|1 2 3|2 3 3
1 2 3|1 2 3|1 2 3
2 3 3|2 3 1|1 2 1
-----------------
1 1 2|1 2 3|2 3 3
2 2 3|2 3 1|3 1 1
3 3 1|3 1 2|1 2 2
-----------------
2 1 1|2 3 1|3 3 2
3 2 2|3 1 2|3 1 1
3 3 1|3 1 2|2 1 2
```

Applying "no 3 the same in a row" to diagonals and antidiagonals:

```
1 1 2|1 2 3|2 3 3
1 2 3|1 2 3|1 2 3
3 2 3|2 3 1|1 2 1
-----------------
1 3 1|1 2 2|3 3 2
2 1 2|2 3 3|1 1 3
3 2 3|3 1 1|2 1 2
-----------------
3 1 1|2 3 1|2 3 2
2 3 1|3 1 2|3 2 1
2 3 2|3 1 2|3 1 1
```

Comment: Yeah, I later realized that this could be again solved with a few variations on a base pattern.

Comment: @PavelPájaHalbich just wondering, will it make any difference if rule2 applies to diagonals?

Comment: @theaxis I may be wrong, but probably not (somebody, prove me wrong please :) ). Imagine some permutation in top left corner, having rule 1 OK. Now you need to fillout other squares, which is only other permutation of the basic pattern. By fullfilling rules step by step, you can win anytime. **BUT** you can actually prove it using neprocedural programming. If you write program in **Prolog**, **Lisp** or **Scheme** (I'd reccomend the first one for this). You just write the rules there and then you ask for a solution.

Comment: @theaxis  For example http://programmablelife.blogspot.cz/2012/07/prolog-sudoku-solver-explained.html This will explain you the basics. And sudoku solver only in 15 lines? In Prolog, this is possible. There you can iterate all your ideas quickly and the most important fact is that it will be *mathematically proven*.